# Accessing UserControl Methods and properties from other Class

Tags: c#, wpf

What i have is a user control which contains a combobox and a DataGrid , what am trying to do is Accessing the UserContorl Methods from within my other Class which is named Class1 , in the class 1 i have some methods which will take advantage of the method in the UserControl(since the user control contains necessary data like combobox.tex)

```
//The user control Code

    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();

         }
       public string Mymethod()
       {
       return Combobox.Text ;
       }
    }

// The other class is 
class Class1
{
//Here i want to access the method from the withen of the userControl Class
UserControl1 cnt= new UserControl1()
//Also tried var cnt= new UserControl1()
Cnt.MyMethod()

}
```

What i have been trying is to create an instance of UserContorl in Class1 but i get no result since it is a new instance . Even at some point i have created a property inside the UserControl Class to pass up neccesary data but no luck as well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expose the form to `Class1` by passing it as a parameter to the constructor:

```
class Class1
{
    private readonly UserControl _userControl;

    public Class1(UserControl userControl)
    {
        _userControl = userControl;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _userControl.MyMethod() etc
    }
}
```